# How to escape from hex to decimal

Tags: c, hex, escaping, decimal

I apologise if this is an obvious question. I've been searching online for an answer to this and cannot find one. This isn't relevant to my code per se, it's a curiosity on my part.

I am looking at testing my function to read start and end bytes of a buffer.

If I declare a char array  as:

```
char *buffer;
buffer = "\x0212\x03";
```

meaning `STX12ETX` - switching between hex and decimal.

I get the expected error:

```
warning: hex escape sequence out of range [enabled by default]
```

I can test the code using all hex values:

```
"\x02\x31\x32\x03"
```

I am wanting to know, is there a way to escape the hex value to indicate that the following is a decimal value?

Comment: Not to be too nit-picky, but that is not a character array. Sometimes this makes a lot of difference, which is why I think it's worth pointing out.

Comment: It's a character pointer pointing at a (read-only) string, but I would probably just call it "a string".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

will something like this work for you ?

```
char *buffer;

buffer = "\x02" "12" "\x03";
```

according to standard:

> § 5.1.1.2 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.
>
> § 6.4.4.4 3. and 7. Each octal or hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of characters that can constitute the escape sequence.

- the escape characters:
- \' - single quote '
- \" - double quote "
- \? - question mark ?
- \ - backslash \
- \octal digits
- \xhexadecimal digits

So the only way to do it is concatenation of strings with the precompiler concatenation ( listing them one after another).

if you want to know more how the literals are constructed by compiler look at §6.4.4.4 and §6.4.5 they describe how to construct the character literals and string literals respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
"\b12"
```

to represent a decimal value. Altough you need to use space after hex values for it to work.

```
buffer = "\x02 \b12\x03";
```

Or just 12

```
buffer = "\x02 12\x03";
```

Basically you need to add a blank character after your hex values to indicate that it's a new value and not the same one

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to end a hexadecimal escape except by having an invalid (for the hex value) character, but then that character is of course interpreted in its own right.

The C11 draft says (in 6.4.4.4 14):

> [...] a hexadecimal escape sequence is terminated only by a non-hexadecimal character.

Octal escapes don't have this problem, they are limited to three octal digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the octal format. Octal code is always 3 digits.
So to get the character '<-' you simple type \215